# Installing tidyjson via CRAN or Devtools

Tags: r, json

I'm trying to install tidyjson.  I looked up CRAN itself, and it appears that [tidyjson has been removed from CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyjson/index.html), but archives still exist and two github repositories still exist holding the package (colearendt/tidyjson and sailthru/tidyjson).

However, I'm having issues downloading the package, either using install.packages or devtools::install_github().

`install.packages("tidyjson")` produces a warning: `package ‘tidyjson’ is not available (for R version 3.6.1)`

devtools::install_github() produces an error `Error: Failed to install 'tidyjson' from GitHub: (converted from warning) cannot remove prior installation of package ‘rlang’`. I get the same error regardless of which of the two repositories I download from.

In neither case does library(tidyjson) then load the package - it is stated not to exist.

Comment: Perhaps you can remove the `rlang` package since this is what the error says (or simply restart R). But more importantly the tidyverse packages have evolved a lot from a few years ago and an old unsupported package might no longer integrate well with them. So installing `tidyjson` might just be the first hurdle.

Comment: Worth noting for future viewers here that tidyjson is back on CRAN now :) Apologies for the trouble!

Answer (score 1):

Managed to solve this problem by uninstalling and reinstalling rlang through CRAN - the error then occurred for digest. Once I uninstalled and reinstalled `devtools::install_github()` worked as expected.